# Como usar o ScrollView e LinearLayout com altura da tela toda?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Tenho meu código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_reserva"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="fabiohcnobre.jhotelcolonialdosnobres.ReservaActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_reserva">


   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/subtitle_reserva"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Porém o `LinearLayout` não pega a tela toda e meu `ListView` aparece apenas um item. Quero que ele vai aparecendo de acordo com o numero de itens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pensando um pouco no seu código, percebo que não é necessário você utilizar um `ListView` dentro de um `ScrollView`, que talvez, eu digo talvez não seja uma boa prática. Para que você não veja apenas um item como está dizendo é necessário fazer desta forma abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_reserva"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:text="TESTE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView1"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/adViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        -> aqui vai ficar o ad <-

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Editei para que o Ad fique alinhado abaixo.

Comment: Obrigado agora deu certinho muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O scrollView só é necessário se vc tiver um componente que deseja ver que esteja a baixo da tela, no seu caso não precisa de scrollView  pq o próprio componente listView ja cria uma lista de rolagem, apos o RelativeLayout principal deixa só seu Textview e seu listView e faz um teste, esse ultimo RelativeLayout se não tiver nada dentro tira ele tmb

Comment: Eu tirei como voce disse editei minhe codigo em cima. Porem o meu ultimo RelativeLayout e o banner do aplicativo nao posso tirar. Queria colocar ele em baixo quando eu tenho uma lista grande de itens o banner fica para baixo da tela.